# Flutter/Dart: getting directory contents with future not working

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to get the contents of a directory and display it on the screen.

When I only have 1 future (and hardcode the return values in the methods) I am able to display them. But when I embed a future within a future (which I need to do to get the application directory and then the list of files), it doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
  Future<List<CardFileInfo>> _getFilelist() {
    var localFileHelper = new LocalFileHelper();
    return Future.value(localFileHelper.getFileList());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Cards")
      ),
       body: Center(
         child: Column(
           children: <Widget>[
             FutureBuilder<List<CardFileInfo>>(
               future: _getFilelist(),
               builder: (context, snapshot) {
                 if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    return Text("Files Found");
                 }
                 else {
                    return Text("Still looking");
                 }
               } //end of builder
             ), //end of future builder
           ], //end of children
         ), //end of column
       ), //end of center
    ); //end of scaffold
  }
```

Here is the code of the localFileHelper.getFileList() method:

```
  List<CardFileInfo> getFileList() {

    List<CardFileInfo> cardInfoList = [];
    final dirName = getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

    // *** if I uncomment the following two lines, the process works *** 
    // cardInfoList.add(CardFileInfo("dummy.tsv"));
    // return cardInfoList;

    dirName.then((dir) { // <---------- problem seems occurs here with the future
      final files = dir.list().toList();
      files.then((values){
        values.forEach((element) {
          var type = element.path.toString().split(".").last.trim();
          if (type == "tsv") {
            var currCard = CardFileInfo(element.path.toString().trim());
            cardInfoList.add(currCard);
          }
        }); //end of foreEach
        return cardInfoList;
      }); //end of files.then
    }); //end of dirName.then
  } //end of getFileList()
```

When I step through the code, the "return Text("Still looking");" line executes at most twice.

The function eventually returns the value, but it seems as if the FutureBuilder doesn't wait long enough for the value to return.

I'm new to Flutter and Dart, and this issue has really perplexed me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition of where the problem occurs is correct; it happens with the `.then` call. The reason this happens is because `.then` returns immediately (it is "non-blocking") and as a consequence the method will return immediately. The Future will complete with no additional values, as the `.then` call won't have completed. At some point in the future, the list should be populated, but you will not know when with the current method.

There are three solutions I can think of to solve this problem:

1. (I would recommend this method) Use the `async/await` keywords to make your method asynchronous more easily. I cannot guarantee this will work as-is (it has been several months since I have dealt with Dart/Flutter), so some syntax might be off, but the ideas are there.

```
 Future<List<CardFileInfo>> getFileList() async {
    List<CardFileInfo> cardInfoList = [];
    final dirName = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

    final files = await dirName.list().toList();
    for (final element in files) {
      final type = element.path.toString().split(".").last.trim();
      if (type == "tsv") {
        final currCard = CardFileInfo(element.path.toString().trim());
        cardInfoList.add(currCard);
      }
    }

    return cardInfoList;
  } //end of getFileList()
```

2. Use a `Completer`. This gives you a bit more control but I would not recommend it in this case as it requires boilerplate and will hurt readability a bit here.
3. Dispatch a call in the `initState` of a `StatefulWidget` that will populate the list, and then use a `setState` call when the fetching is completed to update the UI.

Answer (score 1):

The `FutureBuilder` doesn't work because `localFileHelper.getFileList` is asynchronous but doesn't return a `Future`, so there is no way for `_getFileList` (and ultimately, the `FutureBuilder`) to wait for it to complete.  Additionally:

```dart
  List<CardFileInfo> getFileList() {

    List<CardFileInfo> cardInfoList = [];
    ...
    dirName.then((dir) {
      final files = dir.list().toList();
      files.then((values) {
        ...
        return cardInfoList; // <-- This doesn't do what you think it does.
      }); //end of files.then
    }); //end of dirName.then
  } //end of getFileList()
```

You intend for the `return cardInfoList;` statement to return a value from your `localFileHelper.getFileList()` method, but it doesn't: it returns a value from the *callback* that you passed to `Future.then`. `localFileHelper.getFileList()` instead returns immediately.  Without an explicit `return` statement, it returns `null`. (If you run `dartanalyzer`, it should generate a warning about that.)

`Future.then` itself returns a `Future` that will have the result of executing its callback.  However, you discard the return value of `Future.then`, ultimately losing the returned value and losing the opportunity for callers to wait for the callback to execute.

As stated in [Gregory Conrad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64090661/), using `async`/`await` instead of `Future.then` would simplify your code a lot and would avoid the mistake you're making.  Additionally, I would recommend enabling the [`unawaited_futures` lint](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/unawaited_futures.html) in your `analysis_options.yaml` file to detect such errors in the future.

Comment: Good catches! I completely glossed over those when writing my answer.